# Can deactivating a plugin sometimes "reset" settings within that plugin?

Tags: plugins, options

I need to deactivate a plugin on a client's website to check whether it is causing a certain issue or not. But I'm not 100% sure that after deactivating this plugin, all its settings will necessarily be restored upon re-activating it. Can anyone confirm please?

Comment: No, not 100%, there are specific hooks that trigger on deactivation.  It would be helpful if you mentioned what plugin though.  But, why not make a copy of the site and work locally or on your own server so you don't have to ever mess with a live site?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible for plugin developers to run some functions when you de-activate a plugin, as well as some functions when you activate or un-install plugin.

If you want to look through the code for the plugin you are running, use the Find tool to look for the function [register_deactivation_hook](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_deactivation_hook) which will show you exactly what code will run when you de-activate the plugin.

When in doubt, export the database so that you have a backup which you can restore in case anything awful happens. I think it should probably be okay though.